# Is there any size of tethered kite that is regulated by the FAA?

Tags: faa-regulations

Civilians fly kites for entertainment.

Is there a limit, after which the kite is considered an aircraft and becomes regulated?

Is a kite considered a balloon, after a certain size?  Do technology or other control apparatus make the distinction?  Is it purely height-based, and size is (mostly?) irrelevant?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39514/62)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As one of my instructors was fond of pointing out, there's pretty much a regulation for everything -- [in the US kites and balloons would be covered under FAR part 101](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.15&idno=14#14:2.0.1.3.15.2) which is pretty short and to the point as far as government regulations go.

The big rules regarding kites/balloons kick in for a kite "over 5 pounds" or a balloon "over 6 feet in diameter / 115 cubic feet of gas capacity", and are:

1. You have to keep them at least 500 feet below any clouds.
2. You have to keep them *less than* 500 feet above the ground.
3. You must be at least 5 miles from the boundary of any airport.

If your kite/balloon is going to be more than 150 feet above the surface you're also supposed to coordinate with the closest ATC facility (who would theoretically put out a NOTAM saying "John Doe is going to be flying a kite/balloon/thingy here, between these hours. Please try not to hit it.")

There are also some lighting requirements (if you fly the balloon/kite at night), and visibility requirements (but really, who wants to fly a kite in less than 3 miles visibility? That seems like pretty lousy kite weather.)

---

As a favor to your local pilot community (and to prevent having your wayward kite dragged off by a Cessna on short final) it's probably best to observe the three "big rules" above regardless of the size of your kite - a 6-ounce piece of balsa and cellophane can still make a lot of people's days more interesting if it appears in an unexpected location.

Comment: This article mentions that the (former) Makani energy kite required an FAA temporary flight restriction in order to operate:  https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2019/january/23/new-airspace-obstructions-tax-faa-review-process

Comment: Also, since a kite is a tethered UAV, this stack-exchange question might be helpful: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27468/what-faa-rules-govern-tethered-outdoor-uav-flight